# Fiware orion: Silently fails when delete with # in service path

Tags: fiware-orion

I am using the docker image version of Fiware Orion. When I try to delete entities using a service path ending # I received a 204 but the entity is not erased.

I tried with the next service paths for a \test\testa entity:

```
/#
/test/#
/test/testa/#
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hierarchical search (using `#` suffix) or multipath search (using several service path separated by comma) is only allowed in *query* requests. For *update* requests only single and not hierarchical service paths are allowed.

Delete entity is a kind of update request, so you cannot use the `#` suffix.